# invalid use of incomplete type with default template

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to create a C++ class with a default template parameter. However, I am having the following error:

```
 error: invalid use of incomplete type
```

The code is the follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

typedef std::array<double, 3> vec;
enum Op {Op1, Op2, Op3};

template<class T, enum Op S=Op1>
class classA
{
    public:

    class classInsideA
    {
        public:

        classInsideA() {}

        void tst()
        {
            std::cout << "inside A"<< std::endl;
        }
    };

    void foo();
};

template<class T>
void classA<T>::foo() // not working
{
    std::cout<< "I am being called in here" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    classA<vec> obj2;

   return 0;
}
```

I would like that the default template would not change any of the current syntax in the `class classA`.
How can I fix this?

Edit:
Making the function have 2 template parameters, works.

```
template<class T, Op S>
void classA<T, S>::foo()
{
    std::cout<< "I am being called in here" << std::endl;
}
```

But if the function has a default parameter, why do I need to specify the two templates. Shouldn't assume the default one?

Comment: `classA` has 2 template parameters, but you try to define `classA::foo` with only 1 template parameter. It must be `template<class T, Op S>
void classA<T>::foo() { ... }`

Comment: `template<class T, Op S> void classA<T>::foo() { ... }` does not work. I still have `error: invalid use of incomplete type`, but `template<class T, Op S> void classA<T, S>::foo() { ... }` does... However, why is it not assuming the default parameter?

Comment: You're right, a typo on my side. The default parameter will be used when you create an object of `classA`: https://godbolt.org/z/3MW1e1bP1. For the member function definition, it must be present, because you could also have a partial specialization somewhere `template <class T> classA<T, Op2> {};` and it could also have `void foo()` method. It's just the same like with default function arguments: https://godbolt.org/z/8xxMKxTbb

Answer (score 1):

Simply a typo I believe! You class has two template parameters and your function definition must also use both. See the full example below or [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8e5ffKx4h)

```
typedef std::array<double, 3> vec; 
enum Op {Op1=99, Op2, Op3};

template<class T, Op S=Op1>
class classA
{
    public:

        class classInsideA
        {
            public:

                classInsideA() {}

                void tst()
                {
                    std::cout << "inside A we use Op value"<< S << std::endl;
                }
        };

        classInsideA dummy;

        void foo();
};

    template<class T, Op S>
void classA<T, S>::foo() // not working
{
    std::cout<< "I am being called in here and we use Op value" << S << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    classA<vec> obj2;
    obj2.dummy.tst();
    obj2.foo();

    return 0;
}
```